# Isotop Filtering using "and" and "or"

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have a series a elements that I need to filter based on user selections. The items have classes such as `class="a b c d visible"`. `.visible` is added when it's pin is visible on the map. I am able to filter on `.visible` using:

```
$('.search-results').isotope({
    filter: '.visible'
});
```

However, I want to add the ability to filter on the land, mixed, and residential classes as well. I know that filter can use `and` filtering like:

```
$('.search-results').isotope({
    filter: '.a.visible'
});
```

But, I need to filter the "letter" classes with or, so that if any of them match, and if it has the `visible` class it will show. I have attempted to used something like:

```
$('.search-results').isotope({
    filter: '.a.visible, .b.visible'
});
```

without success. I'd greatly appreciate any help in figuring this out.

tl;dr: Need to match `((.a) || (.b) || (.c) || (.d) && (.visible))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not following your question properly, but what you're asking for appears to be well supported. Take a look at this modified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hu8zdc7o/2/

This code in your example looks correct:

```
$('.search-results').isotope({
    filter: '.a.visible, .b.visible'
});
```

Also, your tl;dr doesn't seem to match your post, did you mean this instead?

((.a || .b || .c || .d) && .visible)